# How to "show" the script, NOT run it..?

Tags: command-line, scripts

So basically, I uploaded a script to textuploader, and then used the wget command to download it to my /etc directory.
Now I am able to run the script by typing: perl 
 ...BUT, what if I want to see whats actually written in the script..? Just as plain text?? Is there any way to achieve this..?
I am sorry, I am really noob, I'm just trying to understand it. Also, my ubuntu looks like this http://puu.sh/7V7FA.png . Nothing fancy like i see on all your others screenshots.

Comment: Use command `cat /path/to/script.pl`.

Answer (score 1):

You can open it in your favorite text editor, or use a tool like `cat` or `less`.

For example:

```
    cat /etc/script.pl
```

Comment: Thank you, here's me trying! 
http://puu.sh/7V8WK.png

The file is named raw btw, and when i execute it I do like this and it works.
cd /etc
perl raw

then it gets executed, but I really want to figure out how to be able to read the script in plain text. (Think is that I actually want to hide it, so it's not possible for someone using my server to actually see the coding i did in the script)

Comment: It seems from your screenshot that the file doesnt exist.
First type this command:
sudo updatedb

then:
locate raw.pl

after that:
cd <location you found>

if you cant find it, then you might have entered the wrong file name or you dont have the file in the first place